# Null pointer exception with string.isEmpty()

Tags: nullpointerexception, javafx-8

My JavaFX program checks to see if a window is closing:

```
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
            Error.reportError("Sucessful Leaf JavaFX run.");
            Error.fileAllErrors();
        }
    });
```

The Error class has a method which reports the error:

```
public static ArrayList<String> errorList;

public static void reportError(String tempone){
    if(!tempone.isEmpty())
        errorList.add(tempone);
}
```

And then eventually prints the error out in a file, a method I found online:

[Mykong = How to write to a file in java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/)

I can't seem to find anything wrong with the code, and I've tried changing `!tempone.isEmpty()` to `tempone != " "` to `tempone != null`, and fileAllErrors has no parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not the string, it's this:

```
public static ArrayList<String> errorList;
```

it should be

```
public static ArrayList<String> errorList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

as you're currently not using an instantiated list, which will always NPE.

However, while we're NPE'ing, Strings are nullable and thus could be null. Consider doing a null check or writing an "isNullOrEmpty" function e.g.

```
public static bool isNullOrEmpty(String inString) {
    return inString == null || inString.isEmpty();    
}
```

Comment: Ahh... apparently, the error was in another method, which I forgot to add the check to. Thanks for the help.